# Why my simple T-Sql Function can not run in Query WIndow?

Tags: function, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I created a function in SQL Server 2012 Express with the code below.

```
CREATE FUNCTION IncAge(@Age AS INT)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @VAR AS INT;
    SET @VAR = @Age + 10;
    RETURN @VAR;
END
```

And when I try to call this function from query window, I get an error.

With `SELECT IncAge(20)` I get error

> 'IncAge' is not a recognized built-in function name.

With `IncAge(20)` I get error

> Incorrect syntax near '20'.

So what is the problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function have to **always** be referenced **with their schema**:

Try

```
SELECT dbo.IncAge(20)
```

It's a generally good idea to always use the schema qualifier (usually `dbo.` -  see [Bad Habits to Kick: avoiding the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)) for everything - tables, views, stored procedures - but in the case of functions, they're mandatory

Comment: Just for completeness they don't *always* need to be `DECLARE @Result INT; EXEC @Result = IncAge 20;SELECT @Result` works fine.